# customize the google search results for my website

Tags: search, google-search

This is the search results for
[Devianart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjXQZ.png)

and this the search results for my website

[en3etni.tn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8CBH.png)

I want to customize my search results like Devianart

Comment: Create a Google+ account for your website also make a Wikipedia content about your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Linkedin

---

First of all you can create a Linkedin profile for your company.

## Google+

---

Just like Linkedin you can create a Google+ profile for your company/business

## Wikipedia

---

On Wikipedia you have an option to create a Wikipedia page for your company/business; In this you can type all important public information of your company (founders, job of company, etc. )

## Twitter

---

This isn't as important as the others although you can make a Twitter page for your commpany/business to promote it even more.

### Conclusion

---

Hope all of these help, as these are main social media platforms to take into consideration to promoting your business to get a better search result.